# C# Detect if usb device is inserted

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, usb

I'd like to now if it is possible to only allow a C# application run if a usb device is inserted?
 The usb device is a Pololu micro servo controler. At the moment I'm cheking if it is connected throug the serial conection if the Pololu is sending a "Char" as I programed It. But some times the Pololu is connected but in a part of the loop where the Char is not sent, so in this case the application won't open even with the pololu connected. Is there a more reliable way to detect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the removable drives through the following code.

```
 using System.IO.DriveInfo;

 var availableDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives()
.Where(d=> d.IsReady && d.DriveType == DriveType.Removable);
```

details of [DriveInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.aspx)
You can also take a quick look at open source project [LibUsbDotNet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/)